# change asp:FileUpload to Visible="true" using a do while statement

Tags: c#, do-while

I am trying to create a page that has a variable number of FileUpload fields, depending on the number selected from a drop down list by the user.

my .apsx code is as follows;

```
            <tr>

            <td>Number of photo's to upload</td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DLPhotoCount" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged_PhotoCount" AutoPostBack="true">

                <asp:ListItem Text="..."></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="2"></asp:ListItem>

            </asp:DropDownList></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>Picture 1:</td>
            <td><asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="Pic1" Visible="false"/></td>
        </tr>

       <tr>

            <td>Picture 2:</td>
            <td><asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="Pic2" Visible="false"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnUploadFiles" text="Upload Files" OnClick="OnClick_BtnUploadFiles" Visible="false"/></td>

        </tr>
```

and my C# is;

```
    protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged_PhotoCount(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Pic = "Pic";
    int PicNo = Convert.ToInt32(DLPhotoCount.SelectedItem.Text);

    if (DLPhotoCount.SelectedItem.Text != "...")
    {
        string StPicNo = Pic + PicNo;

        do
        {                
            FileUpload StPicNo.Visible = true;
            PicNo = PicNo + 1;

        }
        while (PicNo < Convert.ToInt32(DLPhotoCount.SelectedItem.Text + 1));

        BtnUploadFiles.Visible = true;

    }
    else
    {
        Pic1.Visible = false;
        Pic2.Visible = false;
        BtnUploadFiles.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Open to suggestions on any alternatives if this isn't the best way to achieve the required functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a good practice to create file upload control dynamically based on the value selected from dropdownlist.

Sample examples to add fileupload controls using javascript are available under below links

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Uploading-Multiple-Files-using-JavaScript-Dynamic-FileUpload-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24914/Multiple-Dynamic-File-Uploading

The advantage of this is you dont have to do a condition check in code behind file and no code change required if your business requires to add more file upload controls in future.